# SQLAlchemy - Passing a DDL generated Primary Key to Child Model through Relationship

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, sqlalchemy

I currently have a parent/child relationship defined between the Invoice/Item table.

When running the following code:

```
with Session(engine) as session:
    invoice = Invoice(INV_STORE=99, items=[Item(LINE_ITEM=1, BARCODE=1234567),
                                           Item(LINE_ITEM=2, BARCODE=1234567)])
    session.add(invoice)
    session.commit()
```

I get the following error:

```
[SQL Server]Cannot insert the value NULL into column '...'
[SQL: INSERT INTO [ITEM] ([INV_STORE], [LINE_ITEM], [BARCODE]) VALUES (?, ?, ?)]
[parameters: (99, 1, 1234567)]
```

My invoice object creates perfectly, it seems the DDL generated column values are not automatically populating the child object, only the store value I passed to the Invoice object ***(note the lack of INV_NUM in the insert statement)***. Is there something simple I am missing?

Unfortunately, the legacy database we are using requires the table relationship to be configured as such, and there is no auto-increment in place for the Invoice.INV_NUM field.

Here's my model configuration:

```
class Invoice(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'INVOICE'
  
    INV_STORE = Column(Integer, name='INV_STORE', primary_key=True, default=1)
    INV_NUM = Column(Integer,
                     name='INV_NUM',
                     default=text(f"(SELECT MAX(INV_NUM) + 1 FROM INVOICE WHERE INV_STORE = {INV_STORE})"),
                     primary_key=True))
    ...

    items = relationship('Item', 
                         backref='Invoice',
                         primaryjoin='Invoice.INV_STORE == Item.INV_STORE and Invoice.INV_NUM == Item.INV_NUM')
```

And the Child, Item:

```
class Item(Base):
    
        __tablename__ = 'ITEM'

        INV_STORE = Column(SmallInteger, ForeignKey('INVOICE.INV_STORE'), primary_key=True)
        INV_NUM = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('INVOICE.INV_NUM'), primary_key=True)    
        LINE_ITEM = Column(Integer, name='LINE_ITEM', primary_key=True)
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the join syntax was incorrect? I refactored the join to the following, and it worked like a charm:

```
class Invoice(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'INVOICE'

    INV_STORE = Column(Integer, name='INV_STORE', primary_key=True, default=1)
    INV_NUM = Column(Integer,
                     name='INV_NUM',
                     default=text(f"(SELECT MAX(INV_NUM) + 1 FROM INVOICE WHERE INV_STORE = {INV_STORE})"),
                     primary_key=True)

    items = relationship('Item',
                         backref='Invoice',
                         primaryjoin="and_(Invoice.INV_NUM==Item.INV_NUM, "
                                     "Invoice.INV_STORE==Item.INV_STORE)")
```